# How to initialize struct with anonymous array

Tags: c

I'm trying to create nested structs with anonymous array initialization:

```
struct CIpv6Address {
    uint16_t* address;
};

struct CIpv6Cidr {
    CIpv6Address* address;
    uint16_t cidr;
};

CIpv6Cidr cIpv6Cidr1{
    CIpv6Address {
        (uint16_t[]){0xfdaa, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    },
    64
};
```

but I'm getting:

> error: taking address of temporary array
>                (uint16_t[]){0xfdaa, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};

and also

> error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
>            CIpv6Address {

The first error I kinda know why. But I don't want to allocate an array with `new` as it'd need to be `delete`d somehow after. Is there a simple way to simply put a little address there?

And for the second error I have no idea

Comment: C or C++, pick one.

Comment: If you don't want the burden of memory management you don't use pointers.

Comment: @kiranBiradar unfortunately I need to send it through a C interface so I need to use pointers

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C, then. But would it be different?

Comment: For the error2 `(uint16_t[]){0xfdaa, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};` remove semicolon at the end of array initialization.

Comment: It could be; you should retag accordingly. There are no compound literals in C++. Is `CIpv6Cidr cIpv6Cidr1` actually a global variable, or function-local? If latter, can you point the pointer to a local array, or you need it to live longer than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you initialize variables in C. In C initialization has a form like `type variable = value` - there has to be a `=` between the name of the variable and `{`. Also without the use of `typedef` you have to use the keyword `struct` in front of the name.

> How to initialize struct with anonymous array

You can use compound literals. At file scope compound literals have static storage duration, but at block scope they have automatic storage duration - as always you have to watch out for lifetime of objects. You can [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/5vXB9t):

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct CIpv6Address {
    uint16_t* address;
};

struct CIpv6Cidr {
    struct CIpv6Address* address;
    uint16_t cidr;
};

struct CIpv6Cidr cIpv6Cidr1 = {
    &(struct CIpv6Address){
        (uint16_t[]){0xfdaa, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    },
    64
};
```

Comment: oh ok. Just out of curiosity, for C++ was I doing right? Because I tried to compile that on C++. However these structs are supposed to be passed to C code (actually Rust code but with C interface), so that's my confusion about wheter to use C or C++.

Comment: `for C++ was I doing right?` What were you doing? Please define what is "right"? `Because I tried to compile that on C++.` C is not C++. Compound literals is a feature of C that doesn't exists in C++. `However these structs are supposed to be passed to C code` A believe a good read about what is a "plain old datatype" would be advisable. Also because you state `don't want to allocate an array with new as it'd need to be deleted somehow after` a good read about smart pointers and how to use them could be enlightening.